# How to use the output of one command as the bash completion for another

Tags: bash, git, command-substitution

I'm creating a new command and I need a completion function so that when I press tab a couple of times it gives me some alternatives to choose from. The list of alternatives should be the branches available in a git repository.

I've used `complete -W $(git branch | grep -v '^*' | xagrs) my_command` but that creates a static list once .bashrc is "compiled" and it's not dynamic per repository.

Also I've found `complete -c` but that doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`complete` has `-F` argument that let's you generate complete from inside any function. Inside that function run your command `git branch | grep -v '^*'` and fill out `COMPREPLY` appropriately. There are many guides on how to write bash completion functions on the net available - research them and write your own functions for your needs.

Notes: `-W $(...)` - the unquoted expansion undergoes word splitting, so you are effectively running `complete` with a single completion argument. Be sure to research which, how to and when to use quotes in shell.